# Блоки server обрабатываются в порядке следования в конфигурационном файле?

Tags: nginx

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    ...
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org;
    ...
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.net;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Что значит "обрабатываются" ? Вряд ли например для поиска нужного блока используется простой перебор. было бы логично использовать какую нибудь хеш-таблицу и наверняка она используется. А у хеш-таблиц нет понятия "порядок". И что такое "приоритет", кстати

Comment: @Mike Да, там используется хэш-таблица. Приоритет имён серверов это другое (точное имя > маска > регулярка).

Comment: тогда о каком "порядке" идет речь ?

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: @Mike Ну так и ответьте тогда что для хэш-таблицы порядок значения не имеет. Я себе слабо представляю как она вообще работает.

Comment: @KAGGDesign В документации NGINX прямого ответа на мой вопрос нет. Я её всю прочитал.

Comment: Тогда не проще ли попробовать? Минут 10 на эксперимент уйдет

Comment: В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Блоки server обрабатываются в порядке следования в конфигурационном файле? Символ "?" в русском языке означает вопрос.

Comment: Я не понимаю этого вопроса. Что вы имеете в виду под «обрабатываются» в данном контексте?